# Fetch the content of url get stucks when using Cro or HTTP::UserAgent

Tags: web-scraping, raku, cro

I want to get the content of https://translate.google.cn, however, `Cro::HTTP::Client` and `HTTP::UserAgent` just stucks, and `WWW` get the content, I don't know why.
If I change the `$url` to https://raku.org, all three modules works fine:

```
my $url = "https://translate.google.cn";
use Cro::HTTP::Client;
my $resp = await Cro::HTTP::Client.new(
    headers => [
       User-agent => 'Cro'
   ]
).get($url);
say await $resp.body-text();



use HTTP::UserAgent;
my $ua = HTTP::UserAgent.new;
$ua.timeout = 30;
my $response = $ua.get($url);

if $response.is-success {
    say $response.content;
} else {
    die $response.status-line;
}
)

use WWW;
say get($url)
```

Did I miss something? Thanks for suggestion for me.

Comment: It might be that Google detects whether you are using a real browser and delays response if you don't. I would check with other non-Perl6 modules, just in case.

Comment: compare to python's  [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) module, `import requests; requests.get('https://translate.google.cn').text` works well, may be something did under hood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me `HTTP::UserAgent` works and `Cro::HTTP::Client` gets stuck. If you wish to debug things further both modules have a debug option:

`raku -MHTTP::UserAgent -e 'my $ua = HTTP::UserAgent.new(:debug); say $ua.get("https://translate.google.cn").content'`

`CRO_TRACE=1 raku -MCro::HTTP::Client -e 'my $ua = Cro::HTTP::Client.new(); say $ua.get("https://translate.google.cn").result.body-text.result'`

`WWW` also works for me. It is surprising it works for you since it is backed by `HTTP::UserAgent` ( which does not work for you ). Here is its `get` method to show you how it uses `HTTP::UserAgent`:

```
sub get ($url, *%headers) is export(:DEFAULT, :extras) {
    CATCH { .fail }
    %headers<User-Agent> //= 'Rakudo WWW';
    with HTTP::UserAgent.new.get: $url, |%headers {
        .is-success or fail .&err;
        .decoded-content
    }
}
```

Comment: For `Cro::HTTP::Client`, I print the debug [output](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ohmycloud/9e17b7424a583f82009e557b1b188bae/raw/a01b858e39d061d94e43595a5a97938b5c2de7b3/gistfile1.txt), have no idea what it means. As for `HTTP::UserAgent`, It works again when my network environment changed to working mode, I will try again when back home.

Comment: `HTTP::UserAgent` also works. `Cro::HTTP::Client` still gets stuck. I will try more parameters.

Comment: Might be a recent rakudo regression -- see https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2553 Try a slightly older version of rakudo if you want to test this theory.

Answer (score 1):

This could be down to http2 on the problematic https sites. In fact what you are describing is pretty much what I raised in https://github.com/croservices/cro-http/issues/45.

A workaround until a fix is in is to try making requests using http/1.1

`Cro::HTTP::Client.get('https://translate.google.cn', :http<1.1>);`

Comment: Thank you. It may works, but fails with *Unknown string encoding: 'gb2312'*, I have add this error under your issue.

Comment: @chenyf - I would raise a new issue for your the string encoding bug - I don't believe it is related to either http/1.1 or http/2 - which is your original issue.

You could fool google into giving you `UTF-8` encoded text by changing the `User-Agent` header to `User-Agent => "Mozilla/5.0"` and then Cro::HTTP::Client is happier.